# Azure Functions bundle and extension, functions versions - javascript confusion 2.x, 5.0.x+?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I am making an azure cloudfunction with nodejs that gets triggered by a servicebus topic.

Reading this I am super confused, they have a version for everything and nothing makes sense in their documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-javascript

The host.json file has 2 versions, the schema version and the bundle range version. Then the article talks about 5.x+ version, but the default range is 3.3.0 to 4.0 but not including 4. I am very confused what version am I using, what binding options are available to me and none of the articles explain anything in a clear and concise manner.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
    }
}
```

Does this include 5.x+ that they talk about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-javascript#hostjson-settings)? Do I need to make this 5.0.0?

If I use the host above, does this host.json config become invalid? The link above does not show messageHandlerOptions as one of the options (for 5.0.x) but mentions it being ok if not using sessions. Does it only apply for 2.0.x?

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:09:30"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:09:55"
}
```

What is the difference between Function and Extension?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## TL'DR

For "Bundle v3.x" / "Functions 2.x+" Service Bus settings:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:09:30"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:09:55"
}
```

For "Bundle v4.x" / "Extension 5.x+" Service Bus settings (the OP [referenced doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-javascript) does not list this Bundle version but it is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register)):

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "autoCompleteMessages": true,
      "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:09:30",
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:09:55"
}
```

*Visual Studio Code might not recognize stuff but things should still run if you have use one of these.*

## Too Long DID Read

This took me hours to understand as well. [This source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/blob/v4.x/src/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/extensions.json#L39-L47) helped me understand the map between `extensionBundle.version` property in root `host.json` and "Extensions 5.x+" in the Azure Function Service Bus `host.json` settings (as referenced in the ["host.json settings"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-javascript#hostjson-settings) section).

- `extensionBundle.version` property - this is a way Azure injects all of the Azure Function binding extensions at runtime *for non-C# languages* (no need to install NuGet packages since we are working in TypeScript, Python, etc. and not .NET). Also, reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges) helped me understand the `extensionBundle.version` syntax.
- "Extensions 5.x+" - this is the version of the NuGet package in the latest `extensionBundle.version` (e.g. 4.x)

Back to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/blob/3963bbc674cd903326be49360f71361d28f218cb/src/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/extensions.json#L39-L47): this is the branch for the 4.x extension bundle release and it references a `majorVersion: 5` for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` extension (i.e. NuGet package).

My Visual Studio Code still says my Service Bus extension v5.x configuration is invalid but it works. I haven't figured how to fix Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that my answer (below) solves your confusion:

[image]

> Then the article talks about 5.x+ version, but the default range is 3.3.0 to 4.0 but not including 4. I am very confused what version am I using, what binding options are available to me

I think, they have given clarity/information about which `host.json` version to use in C# Programming language and missed that info in other languages in the same documentation.

If you take a closer look by minimizing the documentation to certain extent, then this will provide the clarity on extension versions:

[image]

**Explanation**:

If you use the version 5.x or later of this extension `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`, then you can use the new configuration settings available in `Extension 5.x+` in the `host.json` file.

If you use the version <5.x of this extension `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`, then can use the configurable settings available in `Function 2.x+` in the `host.json` file.

---

> **What is the difference between Function and Extension?**

AFAIK, they renamed the version name as Function 1.x, 2.x, Extension 5.x which are stable versions.

---

> If I use the host above, does this host.json config become invalid? The link above does not show messageHandlerOptions as one of the options (for 5.0.x) but mentions it being ok if not using sessions. Does it only apply for 2.0.x?

As per my understanding - in the documentation, they have new configuration settings available of each version but the `messageHandlerOptions` is available in both the `Function 2.x` and `Extension 5.x` versions of the `host.json` file in Azure Functions Service Bus Trigger Bindings.

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

The [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-javascript) you have provided in the comment gives the details about Azure Functions Runtime Versions like 1.x, 2.x, 3.x and 4.x.

These are the Azure Functions Core Tools Versions required to run the specific language runtime programs.

**For example**:

JavaScript Versions (NodeJS 10, 12 & 14) works good with the `Azure Functions Version 3.x` whereas NodeJS version 16 works good with the `Azure Functions Version 4.x`.

This document also described the Migration steps and breaking changes of Azure Functions Runtime/Core Tools versions from old version to newer version.

> **Do I change the range in host.json to 5**?

Every version of `host.json` i.e, `Functions 1.x`, `Functions 2.x` and `Extension 5.x` are same, they have incremented/discovered new configurable settings in each newer version.

> **I still don't understand the difference between function version and extension version. What version am I running**?

Refer to Explanation Para in the same answer.

In a Simple, if you're using the extension `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` version is equal to 5.x or later, then you can use the settings available in `Extensions 5.x+` block. If that ServiceBus extension version is less than `5.x`, then use the configuration settings available in `Functions 2.x` for the `host.json` file.

Comment: Do I change the range in host.json to 5? They dont say its even available on this list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-javascript.

I still dont understand the difference between function version and extension version. What version am I running?

Comment: You didn't answer the question. If I am using nodejs, do I install version 5.x manually or does it happen automatically? Those nuget packages are only for c#. Am I using 5.x? How do I know what version of the servicebus extension am I running? I want to try dynamicConcurrencyEnabled and it says it's only available with 5.x but my VS code says its not an allowed property.

Comment: Hello @Teebu, could you please check the 1st Section Paragraph in my answer that I given that the `Host.json version 5.x` information given for C#, missed for other languages but i.e., same to all prog languages and I mentioned which host.json version to be used for which service bus nuget version!

Comment: I've re-read it a dozen times. Can you just answer the question instead of telling me to read an animated gif... ELI5 it for me.